# In Civilization V, how can I find out what map type I am playing on?

Tags: civilization-5

When I play Civ V, I always start a game via the Mods menu. The Setup screen under mods lists a many more map types, and I set to random.

However, I am not sure how random it is.  Is it selecting at random from the full list or from the regular game list (which is more limited).

Is there a way while playing the game to find out what map type it is?

Comment: I do think there's a note in that menu that says Earth is not among the maps up for random selection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the load menu, when you click a saved game, you can see a question mark signifying that your map choice was random. If you hover your mouse over that question mark, the tool-tip will display the actual map type which was chosen:

[image: screenshot of game load information]

You can also see a similar graphics in-game by opening the game menu (by clicking the button or hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd>), where you can also hover the cursor over the map type to see what it is:

[image: screenshot of in-game menu]

(had to edit the cursor back in because the screenshots won't show it :)